# Using the word propose in the abstract

Tags: review-articles

I wrote a paper. In the last sentence of its abstract, I wrote: Finally, we propose....

Now, one of the reviewer's said that

"Last sentence of abstract: « we propose » without saying for what use makes the sentence weird."

I can not understand what is the problem of using the phrase  « we propose ».

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very likely that the problem is not "we propose", it's whatever follows. Apparently you said "we propose X" and the reviewer thinks that you should explain why you propose X.